Why does Pandas not scrape the second table?
I want to scrape the 2 tables, but only get the result of the first table.
Why? I'm using the same logic for both tables.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# URL to scrape
url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/keepers/Premier-League-Stats"

# Send a GET request
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Scrape the first table
table1 = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'id': 'stats_squads_keeper_for'})[0]
df1 = pd.read_html(str(table1))[0]

# Scrape the second table
table2 = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'id': 'stats_keeper'})[0]
df2 = pd.read_html(str(table2))[0]

# Print data frames
print(df1) # runs well
print(df2) # is empty


Does this answer your question? how to extract fbref tables from comments?

I dont see this question, because is a other user, not me. Im going to check. Tnks for advance.

Im change for stats_keeper, but dont run well.

It is exactly the described approach, only combined with the transfer to adjust url and id

If you look at the raw HTML code for the page you will notice that the table you are trying to scrape is enclosed in comment tags <!-- ... -->.
The parser ignores the content inside these tags so the simplest solution is to remove the offending text before creating a dataframe from the table content.
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import requests

# URL to scrape
url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/keepers/Premier-League-Stats"

# Send a GET request and remove the comment tags from response text
stripped_comment_tags = StringIO(requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', ''))

df1 = pd.read_html(stripped_comment_tags, attrs={'id': 'stats_squads_keeper_for'})[0]
df2 = pd.read_html(stripped_comment_tags, attrs={'id': 'stats_keeper'})[0]

# Print data frames
print(df1)
print(df2)


If you don't necessarily have to do this with bs, you can also use selenium. It is also very suitable for scraping dynamic content. If you don't want to do without bs, you can also combine selenium with bs.
Here is a working version:
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/keepers/Premier-League-Stats"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)

pd.set_option('display.width', None)

table1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "stats_squads_keeper_for").get_attribute("outerHTML")
df1 = pd.read_html(str(table1))[0]
print(df1)

table2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "stats_keeper").get_attribute("outerHTML")
df2 = pd.read_html(str(table2))[0]
print(df2)

with open("tab1.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(df1.to_csv())
with open("tab2.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(df2.to_csv())

driver.quit()

